# GCKUICastButton initialization failed

Tags: google-cast

I can't create a GCKUICastButton to add to my navigationBar, I got this error:

```
GCKUICastButton.m:340: -[GCKUICastButton initializeDefaultAccessibilityLabels] - Localized string initialization failed.
```

when I ask for a GCKUICastButton:

```
let castButton = GCKUICastButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
        castButton.tintColor = .white
        let castButtonBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: castButton)
```

I got an uninitialized cast button.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug on my pod installation, was missing GoogleCastCoreResources and GoogleCastUIRessource Bundles